# create a tree structure from a set of parent-child relationships

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of arrays which holds parent-child relationships between nodes in a graph. Each of the nested arrays is of the form

```
array( 0 => parent_node_id, 1 => child_node_id )
```

So in this array:

```
0 => array(
   0 => 1
   1 => 3
)
```

the two nodes are 1 and 3, and there is a parent-child relationship between node 1 and node 3 (the outer array index `0` is irrelevant).

```
1 => array(
   0 => 3
   1 => 5
),
```

represents a parent-child relationship between node 3 and node 5 (the `1` is irrelevant).

Here is the parent-child relationship array (note that the array index of the outer array (0, 1, 2, 3, etc.) does not represent anything):

```
0 => array(
   0 => 1
   1 => 3
),
1 => array(
   0 => 3
   1 => 5
),
2 => array(
   0 => 3
   1 => 7
),
3 => array(
   0 => 3
   1 => 9
),
4 => array(
   0 => 1
   1 => 10
),
5 => array(
   0 => 10
   1 => 15
)
```

Here is a pictorial representation of the data structure that it encodes:

[image]

And in code format (although any better ideas for an array structure that I can generate an HTML list from later would be appreciated!):

```
0 => array
   0 => 1
   1 => array
      0 => 3
      1 => array
         0 => 5
      2 => array
         0 => 7
      3 => array
         0 => 9
   2 => array
      0 => 10
      1 => array
         0 => 15
```

Using the information from this array, I would like to generate a tree that I can then use to build a menu in an html page. How can I do this using just my array of parent-child relationships?

I know there are many similar algorithms available on stack overflow, but none that works with multiple roots or the particular array input structure that I am using.

Comment: 0 index is a parent, and 1 index is its child

Comment: Can you also explain the logic going from array 1 to array 2? Where is that `null` coming from, for instance?

Comment: Null means that it doesn't have any childen.

Comment: Index "1" is always the array of children.

Comment: Here you go, I posted the schema of how the tree looks like. Now I have to make a tree array so that I can generate HTML nested list later.

Comment: Even with the picture it's still not obvious how this picture is drawn from the flat array representation. And now it's even more confusing: in your text tree there are two roots, one root on the picture though.

Comment: Iterating through the array you get parent-child pairs. So 1 is the parent of 3...then 3 is the parent of 5...then 3 is the parent of 7...etc

Comment: There are two roots, yes, but they have the same id, so they should be treated as one.

Comment: So where is the "`null` is the parent of 1`?

Comment: And that's one of the problems.

Comment: Well, any better idea to make an array so I can generate HTML list later would be appreciated : D

Comment: Reverse the structure: let every child point to its parent.

Comment: Just tell us wtf are those null values...

Comment: It's just to keep the structure with two indexes always. It means nothing, just that there's no child for that element.

Comment: Ok, I threw out those nulls, maybe it's really clearer right now.

Comment: I've added some clarification to your post because the data structure and the way you have stated the problem makes it much harder to solve. Please correct it if it isn't right.

Comment: Just one more edit in the output array, so that it looks like HTML dom - now it looks pretty logical.

Comment: I can do that, how would it look like then?

Comment: Rewrote and clarified the problem -- it should be understandable now.

Comment: Instead of repeating how the outer indices are irrelevant, just remove them. I think they added to the confusion.

Comment: @i alarmed alien Maybe it's better to understand when the outer arrays are named `A-F` instead of `0-5`. And I'm missing the desired output now :-)

Comment: @Yoshi a lot of coding newbies struggle with the basics of manipulating data structures into different formats. It's all very well for us to say, "Oh, just change this data structure to that", but the number of questions about basic array manipulation that get posted in the PHP section alone is evidence that you can't just assume that someone can alter a data structure to make it easier to solve a problem.

Comment: @Michel Have put in the data structure from the OP, although the OP says above that any data structure from which a nested list could be generated would work. This is a bit of an XY problem as the OP's output data structure is not very intuitive, so (IMO) it's better to focus on the goal, a structure from which a menu could be built.

Answer (score 1):

My contribution.
There are only three kinds of elements in the array:

1. elements that are PARENT
2. elements that are PARENT and CHILD
3. elements that are CHILD

Based on those three rules, you can build a menu:

1. Loop all elements and store parents and children by number.

   ```
   result: 3 parents: 1, 3 and 10.
           6 children: 3, 5, 7, 9, 10 and 15.
   ```
2. Now we need to filter those results:

   **2a:** A LONELY CHILD is an element in **children** and not in **parents**

   ```
          result **real children**: 5, 7, 9, and 15 have no child of their own
   ```

   **2b:** Get PARENT/CHILD combinations by substracting LONLY CHILDREN from all children

   ```
          result **parent/child**: 3 and 10 have a parent and child(ren)
   ```

   **2c:** Get the OVERALL PARENT by substracting PARENT/CHILD from PARENT

   ```
          result: **real parent** is 1
   ```
3. Build a menu, starting with the real children, adding them to their rightfull parents and add those to the overall parent.

And in code...

```
$arr=array(array(1,3),array(3,5),array(3,7),array(3,9),array(1,10),array(10,15));
$menu=array(1=>'menu 1',3=>'menu 3',5=>'menu 5',7=>'menu 7',9=>'menu 9',10=>'menu 10',15=>'menu 15');


  //1. loop array and store parents and children
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    $P[$v[0]]=$v[0];
    $PC[$v[1]]=$v[0];
    }
  //2a: filter out the real children
$C = array_diff_key($PC,$P);
  //2b: get the parent_child combinations 
$PC=array_diff_key($PC,$C);
  //3: Get the real parent 
$P=array_diff_key($P,$PC);

 //Sorting the arrays is only needed if the starting array is not ordered
ksort($P);
ksort($PC);
ksort($C);

  //3: Building a menu
  // Create LONELY CHILDS
foreach($C as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($MC[$v])){$MC[$v]=array();}
    $MC[$v][]='<li>'.$menu[$k].'</li>';
    }

  // Build the PARENT-CHILD menu by adding the CHILDREN to their rightfull parents
foreach($PC as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($MPC[$v])){$MPC[$v]=array();}
    // $MPC[$v][]='<ul><li>'.$menu[$k].'</li><ul>'.implode('',$MC[$k]).'</ul></ul>'; //(OLD) 
$MPC[$v][]='<ul><li>'.$menu[$k].'<ul>'.implode('',$MC[$k]).'</ul></li></ul>';  //**NEW**
}

  // Create the REAL PARENT
foreach($P as $k=>$v){
    if(!isset($MP[$v])){$MP[$v]=array();}
    $MP[$v][]='<ul><li>'.$menu[$k].implode('',$MPC[$k]).'</li></ul>';
    }

  //CREATE FINAL MENU
$menu=array();
foreach($MP as $k=>$v){
    $menu[]=implode('',$v);
    }
//$menu='<ul>'.implode('',$menu).'</ul>'; //(OLD)
$menu=implode('',$menu);  //**NEW**

echo $menu;
```

The result of the above:

- menu 1

  - menu 3

    - menu 5
    - menu 7
    - menu 9

  - menu 10

    - menu 15

**EDIT** changed two lines to create valid HTML

And a [new fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4f605fdceb984888f19b152cbf07556af2afa6d9)

Comment: @i alarmed alien. Corrected it.

Comment: I'm not the OP, so who knows what the desired structure is, but your html is valid now. :^)

Comment: @i alarmed alien. Saw to late it was you and not the OP commenting. Thanx anyway for the remark.

Comment: at least we both have perfect html now, even if the OP never looks at these answers... ;^)

Answer (score 0):

The OP stated in a comment that this would be used to build a menu system, so I have written some code that converts the array of arrays into a more comprehensible data structure, builds a nested list (suitable for using as a menu), and populates the list items with data from a second array of `$content`. For the real thing, the data in `$content` can be a set of links or whatever is desired.

```
# input array
$array = array(
0 => array(
   0 => 1,
   1 => 3
),
1 => array(
   0 => 3,
   1 => 5
),
2 => array(
   0 => 3,
   1 => 7
),
3 => array(
   0 => 3,
   1 => 9
),
4 => array(
   0 => 1,
   1 => 10
),
5 => array(
   0 => 10,
   1 => 15
));

# associative array of node IDs and the node contents
# obviously for a menu, the node contents will probably be links
$content = array(
  1 => 'ape',
  3 => 'bear',
  5 => 'cow',
  7 => 'dog',
  9 => 'elephant',
  10 => 'frog',
  15 => 'giraffe'
);

$tree = [];

# simplify the parent-child 
foreach (array_values($array) as $a) {
  $tree[ $a[0] ][ $a[1] ] = 'value';
}

$roots = get_root($array);

# start our initial list...    
$str = '<ul>';
foreach (array_keys($roots) as $r) {
  $str .= build_tree( $tree, $content, $r );
}
$str .= "</ul>";
echo $str;

/**
 * build_tree($tree, $content, $n)
 * 
 * builds an html representation of a tree using $tree, a data structure
 * containing parent-child relationships, $content, the content of each
 * node of the tree, and $n, the current node in the tree. Calls itself
 * recursively when it encounters a subtree to be built
 *
 * @param array $tree 
 * @param array $content - assoc array of 
 * @param string $n - current node in the tree
 * @return string $html representing the tree
 */
function build_tree($tree, $content, $n) {
  $html = "<li>node id: $n; ".$content[$n]."</li>";
  # does $n exist in $tree -- i.e. does it have a child?
  if ( isset($tree[$n]) ) {
    # if so, start a new nested list
    $html .= '<li><ul>';
    # for each of the children of $n, our parent node,
    # run the build_tree code to create the html
    foreach (array_keys($tree[$n]) as $node) {
      $html .= build_tree($tree, $content, $node);
    }
    $html .= '</ul></li>';
  }
  return $html;
}

/**
 * get_root ( $input )
 *
 * input array format:
 * 0 => [ 0 => parent_node_id, 1 => child_node_id ],
 * 1 => [ 0 => parent_node_id2, 1 => child_node_id2 ],;
 *
 * takes an associative array of parent-child relationships
 * and makes two arrays, one containing all the parent nodes,
 * and one containing the child nodes. The root nodes are
 * those that appear in the parent node array but not the
 * child node array.
 *
 * @param array $input 
 * @return array $r - assoc arr. with root nodes as keys
 */
function get_root ($input) {
  $p = [];
  $c = [];
  $r = [];
  foreach ($input as $k => $v) {
    $p[ $v[0] ] = 1; # parent node
    $c[ $v[1] ] = 1; # child node
  }
  # find the array items in $p that aren't in $c
  foreach ($p as $k => $v) {
    if (! isset($c[$k]) ) {
      $r[$k] = 1;
    }
  }
  return $r;
}
```

Results of the above code ([test it using this online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e47bc090190e31738c88ac02a3d2de336e429539)):

- Node ID: 1; content: ape
- - Node ID: 3; content: bear
  - - Node ID: 5; content: cow
    - Node ID: 7; content: dog
    - Node ID: 9; content: elephant
  - Node ID: 10; content: frog
  - - Node ID: 15; content: giraffe

The raw HTML (run through HTML tidy):

```
<ul>
    <li>Node ID: 1; content: ape</li>
    <li>
      <ul>
        <li>Node ID: 3; content: bear</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>Node ID: 5; content: cow</li>
            <li>Node ID: 7; content: dog</li>
            <li>Node ID: 9; content: elephant</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Node ID: 10; content: frog</li>
        <li>
          <ul>
            <li>Node ID: 15; content: giraffe</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your html doesn't validate ;-) You switched `</li>` and `</ul>` after Node 9 and Node 15